# Fantasy or Romance novel including a girl with a tattoed shoulder and chest

Tags: story-identification, novel

I once read this novel with a girl having tattoos on her shoulder, chest etc. There also was a tattoo artist and one day a guy walks in romance starts, but I forgot if it included vampires or demons but something was there.

It was part of a series.

Comment: Hi there! This is still a bit vague - could you take a look at [this guide on how to ask a good story-ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if that triggers any more memories you could [edit] into your question? For instance, was it written in English? When did you read it? Do you remember what the cover looked like? Such things, to increase the chance of a successful identification. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Not much to go on here, but this sounds a little like *Rain Dance* (now retitled as *Soul Storm*) by D.N. Erikson.  The protagonist has a magical tatoo on one arm (just a light show, but not everyone knows that) and makes a living by reaping the souls of the dead for her boss, a vampire two thousand years old.

There is a tattoo artist, the one who put the tat on her arm, and his son (a good-for-nothing sort), a "dwarf Jotun", only about eight feet tall, a werewolf assassin who tries to kill her near the beginning, a human FBI agent with a magical tatoo of his own and a romantic attraction for the protagonist, and of course the rain goddess who brought her back from the dead.

The book is the first of a series; at least three are available now.